# Test for symmetric property of this ordered pair

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

Suppose the set $$S={1,2,3}.$$

I must show that the equivalence relation $$R=\{(1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1),(3,3)\}$$ is on the set.

The reflexive property states that:
$$(a,a) \in R \;\forall a \in S.$$

Observe that we have $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ and that this subset $R$ of ordered pair obeys the reflexive property.

The symmetric property states that:
$$(a,b) \in R \text{ implies } (b,a) \in R.$$

Suppose we have $R=\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}$, we see that $\{(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)\}$ does not hold.

Any help in correcting my train of thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that if $R=\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}$  then it is not a symetric relation, however $R$ is not that relation.

$(a,b)\in R$ implies $(b,a)\in R$ means that we for each pair of $(a,b)$ in $R$ needs to check if $(b,a)$ is in $R$.

$(1,1) \in R$ We confirm that $(1,1)\in R$

$(1,3)\in R$ We confirm that $(3,1)\in R$.

$(2,2)\in R$ We confirm that $(2,2)\in R$.

$(3,1)\in R$ We confirm that $(1,3)\in R$.

$(3,3)\in R$ We confirm that $(3,3)\in R$.

Thus we have checked all pairs, which all hold. Hence the relation is symetric. You do not need to check $(2,3)$ since $(2,3)$ is not in $R$.

Comment: Am I correct to state that an equivalence relation is a special case of relation on a set?

Comment: Yes, an equvalence relation on a set is also a relation on a set. You are correct.

Comment: Still trying to get my understanding around applying equivalence to sets. 
Let's try to test the transitive property:

By the transitive property:
$$\text{(a,b)$\epsilon $R $\land $ (b,c)$\epsilon $R implies (a,c)$\epsilon $R}$$

$$(1,1) and (1,3) implies (1,3) \text{$\subset $R}.$$
$$(2,2) and (2,2) implies (2,2) \text{$\subset $R}$$
$$(1,3) and (3,1) implies (1,1) \text{$\subset $R}$$
$$(3,1) and (1,1) implies (3,1) \text{$\subset $R}$$
$$(3,1) and (1,3) implies (3,3)\text{$\subset $R}$$
$$(3,3) and (3,3) implies (3,3) \text{$\subset $R}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You check all $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ both in $R$ and see if $(a,c)$ is then in $R$ just as you do.